Prayaschitta/Expiation for breaking promise with friends
I made a promise to a friend but kind of broke it....What is the expiation for it since I feel guilty now.
Also, I will only speak the truth from now on & not repeat it again..Kindly answer it .
Thank You

I think it's good to look at the part where Sudama eats all the grams and lies to Shree Krishna about not eating it.

Thank You bro will look it up
